# Jade adds empty `style` element to `head`

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, template-engine, pug

I'm using [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) as a templating engine for my Express powered node.js application. Maybe it's late in night, but I can't figure out where empty `style` element inserted in resulting HTML.

Live example: http://quotation-mark.herokuapp.com/ (noticed that `<style type="text/css"></style>` at the very end of `head`?)

---

Express' templates setup:

```js
app.set('views', settings.projectDir + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', {layout: false});
```

---

layout.jade

```
!!!html

include /helpers/css.jade

html(lang='ru')
  head
    meta(http-equiv='content-type', content='text/html; charset=utf-8')
    noscript
      meta(http-equiv="refresh", content="0; url=/noscript")

    title= title

    block css
      mixin css('/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css')


  body
    block content
```

---

index.jade

```
extends layout

append content
  h1= title
  p Добро пожаловать в #{title}.
```

---

I've checked couple of times but everything seems to be okay (code, templates, validators). Not a clue… Is it supposed to happen? Am I mistaken somewhere?

Even if there is no `head` in template itself, there is one in browser (which is Chrome 19.0.1084.53), maybe browser adds something? Simple HTML page doesn't have it though:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>h1{color:red;}</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hi!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The HTML generated by your server doesn't actually have an empty `<style>` block in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/noscript"></noscript>
 <title>«Кавычки»</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>«Кавычки»</h1><p>Добро пожаловать в «Кавычки».</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Are you using any browser extensions like AdBlock? When AdBlock is turned on, I see that empty style block in every page I visit.  Disabling the extension makes it go away.

Comment: Oh… You're right. Thanks a lot, now I could go to bed in peace :)

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me insane. Couldn't figure out where it came from.

Comment: That was about to be the last thing I checked thank you!